# ThisWorkbook.Protect and Unprotect in Close and Open events

Tags: excel, vba

I want to unprotect a workbook immediately upon opening it, if it is protected the last time it was closed. I place the following code at the very beginning of the Open event:

```
If ThisWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Then
    Call ThisWorkbook.Unprotect("openpassword")
End If
```

Similarly, I want to protect the workbook right before it is closed. So I place the following codes at the very end of the beforeClose event:

```
If ThisWorkbook.ProtectStructure = False Then
    Call ThisWorkbook.Protect("openpassword",True, False)
End If

ThisWorkbook.Save
```

Neither of those two works! Meaning, if a workbook is already protected upon opening, none of the code in Open event is executed. Not even the unprotect call!

Similarly, in the beforeClose event, all codes **before** the protection part are executed, except the protection part and any codes following it. I have confirmed that by placing it in different places in the beforeClose event.

Anyone could help me with this?

Additional explanation why I want to do this: the workbook is being shared among users with different level of authorized access. Most users face a protected workbook when allowed to work on only certain sheets. Hence, depending on who uses it last, the workbook could be closed in a protected state or unprotected state. If it is unprotected during the usage, I need to protect it immediately upon closing, so that the next unauthorized users will open a protected workbook.

Comment: Have you consulted documentation on [what `ProtectStructure` means](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838601.aspx) before using it?

Comment: Thank you for downvoting my question for no reason. Yes, I have. If a workbook is structure protected, that property is True, else False.

Comment: You try to make the workbook unprotected when user is trusted user, and other users will see protected workbook, is that right?. if yes, then how you tell VBA that the current user is trusted user?.

Comment: Thanks, Fadi, for chipping in. Please see my replies to other helpers. My main problem is that the ".protect" and ".unprotect" subs do not get executed in the events "workbook_Open" and "workbook_beforeClose". All other details including, authorization handling, are secondary and implemented in my codes.

Comment: @user5700405, I tested your code and it run correctly, I add 2 msgbox `MsgBox ThisWorkbook.ProtectStructure` after `.protect` and `.unprotect` and both give me correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that the events are actually firing? Try putting a Stop at the beginning of each event handler to see they are called. If the code isn't executing, what happens if you save it as a trusted document?

Just a few things:
Why don't you force a protection when closing for everyone, and only allow unprotecting when opening for certain people?

How are you determining which users can unprotect the workbook?

You're not saving the workbook as a shared workbook, right? It's a normal workbook, but accessed by different users. Shared workbooks are a bit funny with protection.

Comment: Thank you, PaulG for answering. Both events are definitely firing as the code lines in those events are veritably executed. Only those codes I mentioned in my question do not get executed at all. In fact, any codes following these are not executed. I want to force protection for everyone when closing, that is why I put the protect call in the beforeClose event. I determine which user to authorize by Inputbox username and password, and checking them against my login database. Once the authorization level is established, I then protect/unprotect the workbook accordingly.

Comment: The workbook is not "Shared" in excel. As in the "Shared" feature is off.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
For Each sht in ActiveWorkbook.worksheets
    If sht.Protection = True Then
        sht.Unprotect("openpassword")
    End If
Next sht
```

And the same at the end:

```
Dim sht as Worksheet
For Each sht in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Protection = False Then
        sht.Protect ("openpassword", True, False)
    End If
Next sht
```

In excel - as far as I know - it isn't possible to protect the whole workbook directly but instead you have to protect every sheet.

You can at least try it, if it works I'm happy too :)

CU Kath

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I have found out why. I think the sub ".protect" (both for workbook and worksheet) and its related properties only work when used in a stand-alone sub. When used in an event, such as Open or beforeClose, they don't work.

Comment: I have already seen the .protect in an Document_open()-sub and it worked well. This shouldn't actually be a problem. But if it works with you now, then that's ok :)